# Google sheet COUNTIF compare 2 cells in 2 differents columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this kind of data in a google spreadsheet:

```
NAME    AGE  VALUE1    VALUE2
John     18    1          5
Tyron    22    5          4
May      18    1          6
Lewis    25    8          9
Donald   18    6          7
```

I wanna try to count how many occurrences where VALUE2 > VALUE1 and where age = 18

I tried something like that:

```
=COUNTIFS(B0:B10;18; B0:B10; D0:D10>C0:C10)
```

but that doesn't work

Someone to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6=18,D2:D6>C2:C6)
```

`FILTER()` will also work.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(--(FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6=18,D2:D6>C2:C6)<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for the simple `SUMPRODUCT()` variant =). Another option would be: `=COUNTA(QUERY(A2:D;"Select A where B = 18 and D>C"))` but why make things complicated haha.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks. But you know `COUNTA()` will return 1 if there is no records return by `QUERY()` function. That is reason I ignore `COUNTA()`.

Comment: Fair point! Let's just stick with `SUMPRODUCT()` =)

Comment: @TimothyLEROCH Glad to know! Then please accept the answer (tick mark it).